# Create a nested list from array

Tags: javascript, loops, infinite-loop

This is the 3rd question from Eloquent JavaScript chapter 4.

Basically it wants me to create a function that will make an array into a nested list from array.

E.g. arrayToList([1, 2, 3]) should return:

```
var list = {
  value: 1,
  rest: {
    value: 2,
    rest: {
      value: 3,
      rest: null
    }
  }
};
```

I wonder why my code leads to an infinite loop.

```
function arrayToList(arr) {
  var list = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    var a = arr[i];
    function add(res) {
      if (i == 0) {
        res.value = a;
        res.rest = "null";
      }
      else {
        i -= 1;
        add(res.rest);
      }
    }
    add(list);
  }
  return list;
}
```

Thank you for taking a look!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You subtract `1` for `i` in the middle of the loop if it's not `0` - so it never finishes the `for` - you can use recursion for this!

```
function addToList(obj, arr, index) {
    obj.value = arr[index];
    if (index == (arr.length - 1)) {
        obj.rest = null
    } else {
        obj.rest = {};
        addToList(obj.rest, arr, index + 1)
    }
}

var myObj = {}; 
var arr = [1,2,3];

addToList(myObj, arr, 0)
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/freab275/

Answer (score 0):

You are playing games with your loop counter and the recursion.  Each time `i` is not 0 you subtract one, then the loop adds one.  So with one step back and one step forward you never finish.  Add some print statements to see what `i` is each time you reference it.